# MySQL No ejecuta bien trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo un "trigger before insert" en una tabla en MySQL, que calcula un tiempo acumulado en la última columna de la tabla a través de un procedimiento almacenado que compara el registro que se está insertando con el registro anterior cronológicamente ordenado y del mismo tipo.

El hecho es que cuando realizo insert en forma individual desde una consola de esta forma:

```
insert into personas (Nombre,Zona,Fecha_Hora) 
  Values ('Usuario','Zona 1','2018-05-15 07:50:00');
commit;
```

El trigger se ejecuta bien y completa los datos como corresponden al ir cambiando la Fecha_Hora.

El problema es que cuando realizo insert masivos el trigger se comporta como si siempre se estuviera insertando el primer registro y no calcula los tiempos acumulados.

¿Alguna idea de que me puede faltar o que podría estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2):

el `FOR EACH ROW` deberia solucionar eso y no parece haber una manera para crear un trigger sin esas 3 palabras recervadas mira esta estructura para inserta en una tabla de auditoria:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_prim` BEFORE INSERT ON `primera` FOR EACH ROW INSERT 
INTO auditoria(id,conf) values(null,"si")
```